# [Basic typescript]: set the key of a function returned object to the value of it's param

Tags: typescript, types, autocomplete

How can I set the key of a function returned object to the value of it's parameter?

I have the following:

```js
const makeCache = <A, T extends string>(name: T, base = {}) => {
  const cache = base;

  return {
    [name]: cache,
  } as {
    [key in keyof T]: typeof cache; // this didn't work
    // [key in typeof name]: typeof cache; // this didn't work
    // [key in keyof typeof name]: typeof cache; // this didn't work
    // [key: typeof name]: typeof cache; // this didn't work
  };
};
```

I'm trying to make an autocomplete with the value returned as key:

```
makeCache('root').root // ok
makeCache('hello').hello // ok

makecache('error').notError // error!
```

I've done before, I just don't remember how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```js
const makeCache = <A, T extends string>(name: T, base = {}) => {
  const cache = base;

  return {
    [name]: cache,
  } as {
    [key in typeof name]: typeof cache
  };
};

makeCache('error').error // bombs with notError
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwNYFMDCDgAsUwLwwA8AggDQwAqMKAHlCmACYQzQBOAlmAOYB8AFGARwUALkrkARggi4CAbwC+ASny8Y8gFAwYoSLGCYc+GNNkBuTdphsUUAK5swG6zoDaQkQF1xh7ClJrRRgZFx13VABPGC4YKEiABxQQADMYTxQfOMTktL8cIMtFS01EVAx-fgByFDY2EDYq5QA6Wvq2IA

Comment: It worked, strange it's not working on my machine, but on the website is working just fine, any idea?

Comment: I found it, I shouldn't be changing the type using the generic, unless for example `makeCache<'name', string>('name').name`, that helped, Thanks a lot. :)